# Make Request With Node.JS To Change Vanity Discord

Tags: node.js, discord

How can I change the vanity url code in Discord? My current code returns a 401 error.

Code:

```js
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
setTimeout(async () => {
await fetch('https://www.discord.com/api/v9/guilds/serverID/vanity-url', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bot ' + client.token, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                payload: JSON.stringify({
                        "code":"terbo1"
                      })
            })
            .then(async res => await res.json())
            .then(json => { console.log(json);});
```

Response:

```
{ message: '401: Unauthorized', code: 0 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you need `setTimeout` however you were using the wrong HTTP method on the request: the correct method is `PATCH`.

Additionally, `payload` isn't an option on the Fetch API, use `body` instead.

```js
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const endpoint = `https://www.discord.com/api/v10/guilds/${SERVER_ID}/vanity-url`;
await fetch(endpoint,{
    method: "PATCH",
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bot ${client.token}`,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
     body: JSON.stringify({
      code: "terbo1",
    }),
});
```

Edit: As of 01/12/2022 (12/01/22) [Discord](https://discord.com) have now disabled this ability for bots to "manipulate" this request, *however*, the above script can be used on a `User-Account`, there are risks of being banned doing so, so it is NOT recommended, use at your own risk.